# I need to make a UISegmentedControl that displays both text and Image

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods, uisegmentedcontrol

I need to have a `UISegmentedControl` in my that has both image and text in selection, like shown in the attached image. How is this possible?

[image]

Comment: looks more like a tab bar, you can easily recreate one yourself using four UIButtons

Comment: Segment seemed neater

Comment: you can create it by yourself, plus check cocoaControls if you need it more than just a segment control https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?page=1&q=segment

Comment: segment is neat cause it usually has rounded edges at the ends, and its height is also less with no image + text combination. this one actually looks kinda opposite.

Comment: in this place user UIbutton it is easy to handle

Answer (score 1):

Use BWSegmentControl in that has both image and text in selection,

https://github.com/MendyK/BWSegmentedControl

Answer (score 0):

simply in your Case you can't use segment with that much modification. I will suggest to use collectionView instead of it. Create a customCollectionView it will behave like segment bar. Happy Coding..